# How to use minecraft_server.1.6.4.jar on Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS

Tags: server, configuration

I am not sure whether i should host my Minecraft server with Ubuntu Server OS. All I know is that Ubuntu's OS is faster and the firewall is stronger. I'm a newbie with zero knowledge on Ubuntu and server stuff. Can anyone tell me how to use Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS to create Minecraft Server, or am I simply asking the wrong questions and i should get Ubuntu OS instead??

Comment: Is there no guide where you got the file from that tells you how to install it on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Just run `java -jar minecraft_server.1.6.4.jar` to run this. If you don't know - use commands:

- `ls` for list current catalog
- `cd` for change directory (`..` is change to higher dir)
- `sudo` gives you temporary *root* (superuser) priviligies

If this is small server, this is sufficient. But If you want host public server, read tutorials about `iptables` and safety. Tips:

1. **Never** run server on root user - make another user with small permissions
2. Configure `iptables` or `ufw` - it's firewalls; find tutorial and read it - don't just browse, read :)
3. Remove unnecessary software like `cups`, `samba` etc.
4. Read more about security - example disable root login via *ssh*

Clean? Feel free to ask.